# Is there any way that I can pass 100 000 characters using `SetText()` in SilkTest

Tags: silktest

I came to know that there is limit for Silk Test's `SetText()`. Can we exceed that limit and pass more characters (e.g. 100 000) using `SetText()`?

Comment: BTW: lakh is not really a widely recognised international measurement.

Comment: @deceze : Can we exceed that limit & pass more characters(say 100000 characters) using SetText()?

Comment: Can you please provide some code that shows what you have tried? Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve? Maybe there is a better way of using the Silk Test API for doing what you want to do than using `SetText`.